# How to display the last name, first name, birthday of employee who has the first birthday starting by date of 06.06, from the table tblworkers?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to display the last name, first name, birthday of employee who has the first birthday  starting by date of 06.06, from the table tblworkers? I should use the convert command [convert (varchar (5), birthdate, 104)]

`SELECT Surname, Name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Birthdate, 104) AS 'Brd'
FROM tblworkers
WHERE MONTH (Birthdate) > MONTH (06)
AND DAY (Birthdate) > DAY (06)
ORDER BY 'Brd';`  <-- not working, any solutions?? pls help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the idomatic best way - I suspect not, but one approach that I have used is to repeat the Convert in the order by as follows:

```
SELECT Surname, Name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Birthdate, 104) AS 'Brd'
FROM tblworkers
WHERE MONTH (Birthdate) > MONTH (06)
AND DAY (Birthdate) > DAY (06)
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Birthdate, 104);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you Ordering the data on varchar? it will order the data based on character and not by date, instead just **ORDER BY Birthdate**

```
SELECT Surname, 
       Name, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Birthdate, 104) AS 'Brd' 
FROM tblworkers 
WHERE MONTH (Birthdate) > MONTH (06) 
AND DAY (Birthdate) > DAY (06) 
ORDER BY Birthdate;
```